# How to document that an argument could be any type

Tags: python-2.7, documentation

I have a function that is adding a set of values to a dictionary. Those values could effectively be any type that is JSON serializable. I am having trouble writing effective documentation for the function. Throughout the program I have all arguments listed with the type, name, and description but what should I write if the type doesn't matter? I think it would be odd to say the type is `any` or just omit it altogether.

The current documentation I am working with looks like this, if it helps

```
"""
Adds an entry into payload["updated_values"]

@param dict payload: Payload to be recorded
@param str name: Name of the field we are adding to the payload
@param ### old: # <-- Looking for what to add here  
@param ### new:
@return:
"""
```

Comment: True, it's not any type but it seems like it might be too many to list. I was planning on noting the requirement in the description.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in `python 3`:

```py
from typing import Any

def foo(bar: Any):
    pass
```

Comment: I'm looking for something specifically for the documentation.

Comment: I just realized that this question is tagged Python 2.7. Type hinting isn't an option here then.

Comment: I orginally had it tagged as Python and updated to Python2.7, I originally didn't think it would matter since I forgot that Python 3 has this feature.